# Duplicate dropdown using ASP and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-chosen

[image]

I am getting a duplicate for some reason using the dropdown and chosen select.  Any ideas how I can hide the one on the left? I thought maybe it was a conflict between chosen css and my bootstrap css but even if I remove all CSS links it still happens. Here is my code for the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="card">

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="chosen-select" Width="300px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Test</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Test</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="docsupport/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a `bootstrap-select.js` on my `Site.Master` removed that and it worked fine.